# Rate Upper Limit Inference With New Background

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics, experimental-technique, data-analysis

I am trying to set an upper limit on a process in an experiment. Over a given time period I observe $N_1$ events, which are all likely to be from a background. The background events are a Poisson process. Let's say that I can decrease the rate of background events by a factor of two. How can I calculate the amount by which the upper limit on the signal process rate should change if I now see $N_2$ events?

Comment: So $N_{1,2}$ are simply numbers? Also, what do you mean by "upper limit on the signal process rate"? For a Poisson process, could you not just say the upper limit would be infinity (with vanishing probability)? This entire question confuses me.

Comment: I should be able to constrain the rate of the signal process with a confidence interval. E.g. if I look for one hour and don't see anything then I should be able to exclude a signal rate of 1 per minute with high confidence, 1 per half hour with less, etc.